# Mock model object without setters

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, robolectric, powermock

I'm implementing tests on my Android app and I want to do unit tests on a model. The problem is that I do not have setters as the model is created with Realm or by parsing a CSV file (witch univocity csv parser).
So, how could I create a mocked object with valid values? I have something like that:

```
public class Content {

    private String title;
    private String description;

    ...
}
```

How could I generate a mocked Content object with a title and description data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use java reflection

Comment: Could you give an example about how to use reflection in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code below in your test class:

```
    Field field = Content.class.getDeclaredField("str");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(yourObject, "some value");
```

`yourObject` is a instance of `Content` that you use in your test class.

But you shouldn't fill mock object - you should just define method result for mock object.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning: *reflection* has a lot of disadvantages; for example a simple name change for your fields will go unnoticed; and not lead to compiler errors but to failing unit tests later on.

This I suggest a different solution - providing a package-private or protected constructor that you can use to initialize your fields. Then you do **not** to use reflection; and at the same time, your "public" interface of that class doesn't change either, like:

```
public class Content {

  // unit testing only
  Content(String title, ... ) { ...
```

But of course, you have to do balancing - either you add that constructor that isn't required for production; or you go with not so robust reflection code!